# How to make ++ operator increments stack with shorter code?

Tags: c#, increment

I wanted to figure out a way to make my floating points move and change faster than the typical `x++` so I decided to add more of those increments into the same while loop so they stack

```
While (True)
{
    x++;
    x++;
    x++;
    x++;
}
```

The functionality works but how do i do this with shorter code?

Comment: "make my floating points move and change"? What is the purpose of these `x++`? Can you show some more realistic code than `while(true)`?

Comment: On the same note as @Alexei: `x=double.PositiveInfinity;` - much faster, and no need for the loop!

Comment: @MarcGravell - I think result actually will be much smaller. Would not at some point `x+1` and `x` be the same?

Comment: @Alexei indeed, scale and precision will lose 1s eventually. My point was mainly to echo your observation that the question is meaningless without more context. Heck, `while(true);` would function the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace that with:

```
while (...)
{
    x += 4;
}
```

This represents `x = x + 4`

You can also do this with subtraction, multiplication, and division, respectively `-=`, `*=`, and `/=`. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
x += 4; // Adds 4 to x, and stores the result in x.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `+=` operator:

```
x+=4;
```

in this way x will be incremented by 4.